# Return value to a text if all cells are set to FALSE using =Index

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i am trying to write a formula which when multiple cells are all "False" the cell will change to "Nothing" else if one of them is "True" it will change to that Cell tab name.

the thing is it worked fine regarding the 2nd part

[[image: Gif Picture 1]

and i used this formula

```
=INDEX($S$3:$V$3,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($S$4:$V$4=O16)*(COLUMN($S$4:$V$4))))-COLUMN($S$3)+1)
```

but the problem is when all are False i get `#VALUE!`
so i found this code here on Stack

```
=IF(ISBLANK(<range>),"-",<your code>)
```

and used it on my Formula as follows

```
=IF(ISBLANK(W4),"-"=INDEX($S$3:$V$3,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($S$4:$V$4=O16)*(COLUMN($S$4:$V$4))))-COLUMN($S$3)+1))
```

but i got False all the times without change

[image: Gif Picture 2]

Answer (score 1):

i manged to fix it as Dominique recommended and i added 2 new cloumns one of them which is the old fourmla

```
=INDEX($S$3:$V$3,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($S$4:$V$4=O16)*(COLUMN($S$4:$V$4))))-COLUMN($S$3)+1)
```

the 2nd one is

```
=IF(W4="Nothing","FALSE","TRUE")
```

and edited the Status tab to be

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(X4,O17)),W4,Y4)
```

and at O17 a text wrriten "FALSE".
so if checked any box the tab name will be wriiten in Status else if none checked it will be wrriten Nothing.

Gif example:

[Final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckDvd.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a piece of advise: the `=OR(...)` function turns a bunch of `FALSE`s into one `FALSE`, but as soon as you have one `TRUE`, the result becomes `TRUE`:

[image]

Comment: thanks alot i manged to fix it by creating 2 new column one of them is to set True or False if the "Nothing" cloumn is empty or not then i used and typed at O17 "Nothing" so if X4 was empty it will use Y4 which is where the new fourmla for the tabs naems or else if none of them checked Nothing will be written =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(X4,O17)),W4,Y4)